# Problem with generic interfaces not working in C#

Tags: c#, generics

I have an interface:

```
interface IKey<TId, TName>
    where TId: IEquatable<TId>
    where TName: IEquatable<TName>
{
    TId Id { get; set; }
    TName Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then I implement IKey like this:

```
class Item : IKey<int, string>
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
    //...
}
```

And I have collection that should work with these items

```
class ItemCollection<T>
    where T : IKey<TId, TName> //Any type that implements IEquatable<...>
    where TId: IEquatable<TId>
    where TName: IEquatable<TName>
{
    //...
}
```

And the problem is that it doesn't work. Is there a way I can do this correctly?

There is another implementation whithout `IEquatable`, using `IKey<out TId, out TName>` and `IKey<object, object>` but it doesn't work with value-types and uses `Object.Equals`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is your attempting to use `TId` and `TName` in `ItemCollection` without ever defining them.  Because they are part of the interface constraint on `T` they need to either be concrete types are specified as type parameters.

```
class ItemCollection<T, TId, TName>
    where T : IKey<TId, TName>
    where TId : IEquatable<TId>
    where TName : IEquatable<TName>
{
    //...
}
```

Example using hard coded types

```
class ItemCollection<T>
    where T : IKey<string, string>
{
    //...
}
```